# How does a basic data flow works between ReactJS, Apollo Graphql and GRPC, backend

Tags: reactjs, graphql, grpc, apollo, react-apollo

How does the flow of data takes place between Reactjs , Apollo Server , Graphql and GRPC backend . I have to implement all this tech stack can't figure out , how the communication or the data flow happens from UI to backend using Apollo server where backend(GOlang) is using GRPC . And UI is on ReactJS ? And also how it gets connected to db ?

Comment: this is very broad can you let us know what area in particular you're having trouble with

Answer (score 1):

Typically, you'd use ReactJS with Apollo client to connect to an Apollo Server. The Apollo Client will talk to the Apollo Server using GraphQL queries and mutations.

Not sure where the gRPC back-end would sit in this case. But you would typically put the Apollo Server between your client and other external services/databases. Same goes for the database.

```
------------------------------------------
| ReactJS with Apollo Client (front-end) |
------------------------------------------
                   |
                GraphQL
                   |
      ----------------------------
      | Apollo Server (back-end) |
      ----------------------------
         |                     | 
    DB connector          gRPC connector
         |                     |
------------             -----------------
| Database |             | gRPC back-end |
------------             -----------------
```

Comment: gRPC is a communication protocol, and a library that implements that protocol. I don't think it fits where you put it in that diagram.